# Symfony2 MappingException with SonataCommentBundle

Tags: symfony, foscommentbundle

i use SonataCommentBundle version ~2.2@dev, after integrating this bundle
i try with  `http://xx.out.tn/app_dev.php/comments/threads` it gives me :

```
The class 'Application\Sonata\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity, Sonata\PageBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity, Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity, Sonata\UserBundle\Entity, Sonata\NotificationBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\Entity, FOS\CommentBundle\Entity, Sonata\CommentBundle\Entity, Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity, Spy\TimelineBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\TimelineBundle\Entity, Sonata\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity, Sonata\TimelineBundle\Entity
```

there's my config.yml :

```
fos_comment:
    db_driver: orm

    class:
        model:
            comment: Application\Sonata\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment
            thread:  Application\Sonata\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread
    form:
        comment:
            type: sonata_comment_comment

assetic:
    bundles: [ "FOSCommentBundle" ]
```

routing.yml :

```
fos_comment:
    type: rest
    resource: "@FOSCommentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /comments
    defaults: { _format: html }
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to add Application Sonata Comment Bundle and NOT Sonata CommentBundle SonataCommentBundle

this

```
new Application\Sonata\CommentBundle\ApplicationSonataCommentBundle()
```

instead of

```
new Sonata\CommentBundle\SonataCommentBundle()
```